# Slider control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am using slider control for an audio player in silverlight application. The slider is not moving while audio is playing. 
The below one is my XAML code . How to get it?

```
<Slider x:Name="Slider" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
  MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseClicked" MouseLeftButtonUp="MouseReleased" 
  ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Height="30" Width="484"   ></Slider>
```

Code behind for slider events:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
  {
     Audio.Pause();
     Audio.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Slider.Value);
     Audio.Play();
  }

  private void MouseClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     Audio.Pause();
     Audio.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Slider.Value);
  }

  private void MouseReleased(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     Audio.Play();
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758637/slider-controle-is-not-moving-automatically

Comment: Please delete this duplicate of your previous question.  I have moved the code you included to that question already.

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight 3(as i know) MouseLeftButtonDown not working. You need to create own Handler in code. For example :

```
progress_bar.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(progress_bar_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
```